# Matlab's 'save' function - how to name the variable inside the .mat file same as file name?

Tags: file, variables, matlab, function, save

I want to save the result of the `q` for each `case_no` in corresponding string of the `q_cases` as a .mat file. With my statement of `save(q_cases{case_no},'q')` even though the names of files are coming as the corresponding string of `q_cases`, however all those .mat files contain variable with the same name of `q`. When I open those .mat files I get a variable with name `q` for all the 3 files. However, I want the names of the variables stored in those files same as the name of the files i.e. `q_a`, `q_b` and `q_c` respectively.

Comment: Can you just make a copy the variable with your desired name before saving it? After you have saved the variable with new name, you can use `clear` to remove it from the workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to assign the variable name with [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html).

**EDIT**

Eval is usually not recommended, since it is difficult to debug/maintain. Thus, you can instead create a structure first and use the [`-struct`-option of save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html), like this:

```
for case_no=1:length(n)
       [q,S]=q_from_A(nModel,nModel_want,nCell,T,A{case_no},B{case_no},C{case_no},D{case_no},E{case_no},F{case_no});
    %# create structure for saving
    saveStruct = struct(q_cases{case_no},q,...
        S_cases{case_no},S);
    %# ... and save it
    save(q_cases{case_no},'-struct','saveStruct',q_cases{case_no});
    save(S_cases{case_no},'-struct','saveStruct',S_cases{case_no});
end
```

Comment: @Harpreet: Glad to help. I have fixed the variable names, btw.